# line break introduction in confirm message string

Tags: javascript

I have a confirmation pop-up dialog in which I am passing a variable which is a comma separated string.

How can I replace the commas and introduce a line break?

I tried using replace. I tried passing `'\n'` separated list from back-end. But nothing seems to work — though a normal `confirm()` used for testing purposes is working fine.

```
var listcontrol = document.getElementById(id3);
var List = listcontrol.innerText;
var finallist = List.replace("\n", "\n");

if (checkboxCell.checked == false) {
    if (labelCell.innerText == "Yes") {
        confirm("The selected exam is present in the following certifications: " + "\n" + finallist + "\n" +
        "Uplanning this exam here would unplan the same exam under other certification(s) also.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code you are replacing `"\n"` with `"\n"`, which would make no difference.  You want to replace `","` with `"\n"` instead, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "Demetrius Navarro,Tony Plana,Samuel L. Jackson";
alert(string);
alert(string.replace(/,/g, "\n"));​​​​
```

Live test - http://jsfiddle.net/9eZS9/

Comment: Your JSFiddle is pointing to a different test (with the `,` and line breaks switched in test and regex). Here's probably what you meant: http://jsfiddle.net/9eZS9/3/

Comment: That's what the op asked for: comma to line break. And what you put in your answer... so yes, we're looking for comma->line break in JSFiddle too.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Js replace is,

*`string.replace(searchvalue,newvalue)`*

var finallist = List.replace(/,/g, "\n");

Comment: This will only replace the first comma. For a global replace the first parameter needs to be a regex with the global flag set.

Answer (score 0):

If your "pop-up dialog" is a custom html/css-based dialog then newline characters would be treated (more or less) the same as space characters. You'd need to use `<br>` elements instead, so:

```
var finallist = List.replace(/,/g, "<br>");
```

Note the use of the regex as the first argument for replace() - this is needed in order to do a global replace.

For use in a standard confirm you'd need newline characters like you were doing, but with a regex rather than a string for the replace() search term:

```
var finallist = List.replace(/,/g, "\n");
```